# How to cover the RXJS pipe function in Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

I want to cover the pipe function of RXJS in Angular/Jasmine.

I get this error:

`TypeError: this.element.children.pipe is not a function`

The code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.element.children.pipe(
      mapObservableArray((children: ObservableTree<ItemModel>) => children.value.properties))
        .subscribe((props: Properties[]) => {
        // do something with the props or children
        this.childrenElements = props as any;
    });
}
```

This ensures that I can retrieve the values of the children and save it on the this.childrenElements.

.spec file:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { myComponent } from './my.component';

describe('myComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [CommonModule],
      declarations: [myComponent],
      providers: [],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the component', async () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
    const componentInst = fixture.componentInstance;

    componentInst.childrenElements = [
      { name: 'name1' },
      { name: 'name2' }
    ];

    // when
    componentInst.ngOnInit();

    // then
    expect(componentInst).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Tried to stub with:
`spyOn(componentInst.element.children, 'pipe').and.stub();`

But that didn't help.

The this.element.children:
[image]

How can I cover this part of my code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to stub out the observable like data of `element.children` (whatever it is).

This is the first time I am seeing `mapObservableArray`, so I assume that is an in-house operator.

Try:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
.....
 it('should create the component', async () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
    const componentInst = fixture.componentInstance;

    (componentInst as any).element = {
      children: of(/* mock how the children property should look like */);
    };

    // when
    // componentInst.ngOnInit();
    // don't call ngOnInit directly, the first detectChanges will call ngOnInit for you
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // then
    expect(componentInst).toBeDefined();
  });
```

If `element.children` is derived from another observable, you have to mock the other observable same way as I showed you and it should flow nicely.

**Edit**
Try assigning it to an object like I have above. If element is readonly or private, then it will be difficult to mock. Try doing `(componentInst as any)` although I don't think this is the best practice. Maybe remove the readonly or private aspect of it for testing purposes. The screenshot you sent me is the wrapped observable, you have to put the unwrapped value inside of the `of`.

Comment: Can you give a example how to mock? I added a screenshot of element.children in the first message.

When I try to mock, I get

`(property) ObservableTree<ItemModel>.children: Observable<ObservableTree<ItemModel>[]>
The children of this node
Cannot assign to 'children' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)`

Comment: I have added an edit. What is `this.element`? Is it an object?

Comment: there are observables inside the `this.element`. Now with your changed code the test is inside the pipe. But this time I get an error on props.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined thrown`

Comment: Does `properties` exist in `element`? And if so, you will have to mock it the same way.